# PECL returns no ZTS

Tags: php, linux, compilation, pecl

I've compiled PHP7 with ZTS, but when I'm trying to install pthreads PECL says:

`` checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
eska@MSI:~$ php -version
PHP 7.2.0-dev (cli) (built: Apr 30 2017 16:37:02) ( ZTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
eska@MSI:~$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 7.2.0-dev
Zend Engine Version: 3.2.0-dev
Running on: Linux MSI 4.8.0-49-generic #52~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 10:55:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 ``